# Building C# Solution in Release mode using MSBuild.exe

Tags: c#, msbuild, release, mode, solution

I am able to build a solution using MSBuild.exe, but my issue is I can only manage to get it to build in DEBUG mode. I need to build my solution in Release mode using MSBUILD.

Here is what I've tried

```
Process msbuild = Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MsBuild.exe", solutionfilepath + " /P:Config=Release");
```

and

```
Process msbuild = Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MsBuild.exe", solutionfilepath + " /P:Configuration=Release");
```

Answer (score 285, accepted):

```
MsBuild.exe [Path to your solution(*.sln)] /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.0
```

Comment: Why would you specify a TargetFramework as a parameter? That's supposed to be configured by the individual projects within the solution.

Comment: @Triynko Useful when the project is being built in machines with different framework versions (visual studio not installed, only the SDK), v4.7 was not backward compatible with v4.7.2 in my case.

Comment: Using the version of MSBuild that comes with Visual Studio 2022, all parameters require a leading dash (-) instead of forward slash.