# how to programmatically compile a project with a given Release config?

Tags: .net, vb.net, build, msbuild-4.0

I want to build a project in VB.NET by using a .vbproj-file. Inside the file are two build-configurations, one Debug, one Release.

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
        <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DocumentationFile>program.xml</DocumentationFile>
        <NoWarn>42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
        <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
        <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
        <WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
        <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>\\192.168.1.15\program\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DocumentationFile>program.xml</DocumentationFile>
        <NoWarn>42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
        <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
        <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
        <WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
     </PropertyGroup>
```

I'd like to use all these given information of the release config to rebuild the project, but I don't know how. This is my code so far:

```
    Dim logger As ConsoleLogger = New ConsoleLogger()
    Dim loggers As New List(Of ILogger)()
    loggers.Add(logger)
    coll.RegisterLoggers(loggers)

    Dim params = New BuildParameters()
    params.Loggers = loggers
    params.DetailedSummary = True

    Dim instance As ProjectInstance = New ProjectInstance(vbprojFile)

    Dim request = New BuildRequestData(instance, New String() {"Build"})

    BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.ResetCaches()
    Dim result As BuildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(params, request)
```

This builds a Debug-version of the project in a location relative to the vbprojFile. I want it to build a Release-Version into `\\192.168.1.15\program\Release\`.

Is there something like

```
Dim request = New BuildRequestData(instance.Configuration("Release"), New String() {"Build"})
```

I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: Might be relevant: [Building C# Solution in Release mode using MsBuild.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25494747/1189566)

Comment: exactly this `/p:Configuration=Release` part I need as code within my project.